Several WebApplication instances in one .net core process
I'm trying to mitigate a constraint when you can't share an IIS app pool between different .NET Core application.
I have an app that consists of MVC site and WebAPI projects, both running .NET 4, and both are using the same app pool. It worked okay for ages. Now I want to convert them to .NET 8.
As far as I get it, the only (possible) option for me is to merge this 2 projects into a single one. It sounds like quite a stupid work to do. And I just hate an idea of having those two using the same code-infrastructure (e.g. DI containers). So I'm looking for some sort of silver bullet, that will solve all my problems. Is it possible to have several WebApplication instances serving different routes like:
var builder1 = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Services for app1
builder1.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyServiceForApp1>(); 

var app1 = builder1.Build();
app1.MapGet("/", (IMyService myService) => myService.DoSomething()); // Routes for app1

var builder2 = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Services for app2
builder2.Services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyServiceForApp2>(); 

var app2 = builder2.Build();
app2.MapGet("/", (IMyService myService) => myService.DoSomething()); // Routes for app2

// Main application
var mainBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var mainApp = mainBuilder.Build();

// THIS ONE DOESN'T COMPILE
//And here I need the trick to be done, different prefixes redirecting to different apps
mainApp.Map("/admin", app1);
mainApp.Map("/api", app2);

// Start the main application
mainApp.Run();

PS:I can't use out of process hosting. I can't create an additional app pools

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different platform and runtime. Why do you care about app pools in the first place? And what do you mean by "several webapplication instances"? There's only one executable application that has multiple endpoints. The same application can have MVC, Web API or Minimal API endpoints but in the end, all are offered by the same application

The question's code can't work, period. a constraint when you can't share an IIS app pool why do you consider this to be a constraint? solve all my problems what are these? Do you want to avoid setting the execution account for every pool? Avoid replicating app pool settings? The app pool isn't an end in itself, it's one of the way some features are bundled. But not the only one. You'll have to focus (and add to the question) what you really want to find the equivalents in ASP.NET Core


Why do you care about app pools in the first place?
Because I have the same application running on ~150 sites per physical server. Every additional app pool adds a serious RAM pressure



And what do you mean by "several webapplication instances"?
I tried to describe it in the code. It would be great to be able to route certain requests to the certain app like: mainApp.Map("/admin", app1);


The code doesn't work and doesn't show what you assumed. Don't assume there's RAM pressure based on how a different platform behaved 12 years ago. Measure the actual RAM usage. The garbage collector is completely different. The app pool isn't even a managed pool. The web app is solely responsible for allocation and GC

As for running on ~150 sites per physical server. that's what Docker and Kubernetes do, and ASP.NET Core was built to work that way without the overhead of a separate web server. Since .NET 7 you can even publish directly to a docker image instead of a binary

I think you sidetracked a bit. I'm aware about docker/k8s options. They are not an option  here for various reasons though. Your assumption that I did not measure the actual RAM usage is wrong as well. It was proven that I can't afford another app pool for this application. It gives ~50 GB overhead to the server in total and 0.5TB to the whole system we're running

That means the code is leaking. Fix the leak. 50GB RAM usage in an ASP.NET Classing application is stupefyingly humongous. There were very few web servers with 50 GB RAM in ASP.NET Classic's heyday, back in 2012. And they cost a fortune

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There's no point. You can't have shared app pools. Any web app that used 50GB RAM back in 2012 would be terminated instantly. I can't guess what the old code was doing, but you aren't in that platform any more. With such RAM usage you could easily afford a Redis cache used by all servers

BTW I worked for one of the largest online travel agencies using ASP.NET. Thousands of searches per second, lots of servers, lots of caching, and metasearchers like Kayak or Google would ignore you if a trip search took more than 10s. My boss would freak out if I asked for 50GB RAM for the web server. Never mind telling him one web app needed 50GB

Man, we're one of the biggest e-commerce platform in North Europe. We have ~1500 shops running their business with us every day. Our system consists of 15 clusters 3 to 10 webnodes each. Each webnode runs from 1 to 150 shops. Each shop is a single IIS website. You really think, that if I add one tiny-tiny app pool that will do nothing except loading .NET runtime into it to every shop, it'll have 0 memory impact?
Bear in mind that each shop is behind LB, so in fact I have to add 1 app pool times shop count times webnodes per shop

I see and raise 4th air travel agency in Europe (back then), with millions of air travel searches per day. And each search result from airlines could be 1MB XML. Got acquired by #1 global 6 years ago. I know what IIS does, what cascading meltdowns look like, how memory gets allocated. I wrote part of the code that did air searches.

And I respect your achievements, but as I mention we're sidetracked from the topic. Cheers

No we haven't. You can't share pools, period. The real issue is how multi-tenancy was designed, not app pools. And how to pack multiple shops together. I assume you use the HOST header for shop domains, and separate web sites per shop, all sharing the same app pool. There are several ways to implement multitenancy in a single app but none involves multiple WebApplication instances. You can use YARP as a reverse proxy instead to convert shop URLs to easily routable URLs like /shops/123/catalog

You can probably use IIS URL Rewriting instead of YARP to rewrite tenant URLs too.

Each shop is a single IIS website. Yeah, no wonder you are using 50GB of RAM. Is it an option for your new thing to be multi-tenant such that you can have a single instance serving all of those sites?

I mention we're sidetracked from the topic When people are stuck in the XY Problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) they often think people are being unhelpful. But @PanagiotisKanavos is correct here. The whole way you are thinking about the problem, and attacking it, is fundamentally wrong. Take a step back, and look at the appropriate .NET (Core) patterns to apply here.

If this business is so large, one of the biggest e-commerce sites in Europe, then I suggest you seek professional advice.

keep both the project separate instead of merging them, and even though both projects might share some infrastructure, you can keep separate DI containers for each project. based on your description and size of your origination we can understand creating separate pool is not easy but it is recommended to use a separate app pool for each application or site to ensure isolation and stability. merging the project in one is lot of work and not easy
